# Inductance in gapped core vs a long solenoid

Tags: inductance

The inductance for a long solenoid with a ferromagnetic core is easily calculated.
$$L = \mu N^2\frac{A}{L_{core}}$$

For a toroid, it is similar, but the length is the circumference of the toroid.

$$L = \mu N^2\frac{A}{2\pi r}$$

For a toroid with large gap, it seems like the gap reluctance dominates, so one can approximate this as

$$L = \mu_0 N^2\frac{A} {L_{gap}}$$

If this is all true, (and maybe I am misunderstanding something) I am tempted to view a long solenoid as simply an unclosed toroid.  But clearly this leads to a difference of $\frac{\mu}{\mu_0}$, which is very large.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: please, use mathjax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Assuming large $\mu_r = \frac{\mu}{\mu_0} \gg 1$, in a toroid the H field is exactly $H=N\frac{I}{2\pi r}$ and because there are no poles H is circular and parallel everywhere with $B = \mu_r \mu_o H$. In a straight long, narrow and tightly wound solenoid there are poles at the ends of the core. These poles induce a field opposite in direction to the field of the coil current, so that in the middle of the core the field is smaller. When you bend this coil so that the ends be close to each other, that is the gap between them is much shorter than the length of the core, then you concentrate the *outer* field in the gap but without changing much the already small field in the middle of the core.

---

In analogy of Ohmic resistance introduce the concept of *reluctance* with the definition $\mathcal R =\frac{\ell}{\mu_r\mu_0 A}$. The analogy is a good one for flux is conserved the way current is and the "ampturns" or *mmf*, ie., $NI$ being equal to the product of reluctance and flux is similar to *emf*. Also, the inductance can be written as $L=\frac{N^2}{\mathcal R}$. Because the flux is common, reluctances add when in series, and you can write for the gapped toroid core that its reluctance is $$\mathcal R_0 = \mathcal R_c + \mathcal R_g = \frac{\ell_c}{\mu_r\mu_0 A}+\frac{\ell_g}{\mu_0 A}$$ and then its inductance will be
$$L_0 =\frac{N^2}{\mathcal R_0}
=\frac{N^2}{\frac{\ell_c}{\mu_r\mu_0 A}+\frac{\ell_g}{\mu_0 A}}\\
=\mu_0\frac{N^2A}{\frac{\ell_c}{\mu_r}+\ell_g}$$
If now $\frac{\ell_c}{\ell_g}\ll \mu_r$ you get your formula:
$$L_0\approx \mu_0\frac{N^2A}{\ell_g}$$

Comment: Okay. Yes...mu_r is assumed large. "When you bend this coil so that the ends be close to each other, that is the gap between them is much shorter than the length of the core, then you concentrate the outer field in the gap but without changing much the already small field in the middle of the core."   Are you saying my equations are valid?  Second:  We have another choice--rather than bending the long solenoid into a near circle we could simply add a horseshoe of high mu material around our long solenoid.   Are you saying the distribution of coils around the ferromagnetic material matters?

Comment: See above more details on the 1st question. Regarding your 2nd question, all I can say is that if the coil is around the core all the way wrapped to the end of the gap or to the end of the straight rod the resulting inductor will be quite different than if it were wound only around the middle of the core, but I am not sure if this what you are asking about.

Comment: This is part of the challenge:  It seems to me that the reluctance analogy is similar to electrical resistance: current is the same everywhere in the circuit.  So, the MMF is the same everywhere.   I am having trouble reconciling this with notions that the field in the center of the long coil is different than the ends, or that the coil distribution along the core matters.