# Deviation in the calculation for magnetic locking between two approaches

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am sizing a system for an electromagnetic locking and I have a deviation between two approaches to calculate the separation force from the electromagnet. The potential energy $E$ and the separation force $F$ are given by:
$$E = \frac{VB^2}{2\mu_0} \qquad F = \frac{\text{d}E}{\text{d}l_\delta}$$
where $V$ and $l_\delta$ are respectively the volume and length of the air gap created by the separation. Now there are two approaches to calculate $B$. The first one is via a magnetic circuit analysis:
$$NI = AB \sum_i R_i = AB \left(\frac{l_{\text{core}}}{\mu_0\mu_{\text{core}}A} + \frac{l_\delta}{\mu_0A}\right) $$
With $R_i$ the reluctances of the air gap and the core material. Since the air gap length is infinitesimally small, we get
$$B = \frac{NI \mu_0\mu_{\text{core}}}{l_\text{core}}.$$
The approach I read in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_lock) was different, and they used Ampere's law to calculate $B$ with
$$B = \frac{NI \mu_0\mu_{\text{core}}}{l_\text{eff}}.$$
With $l_{\text{eff}}$ the effective length of the solenoid. Both methods deviate by the length in the denominator. Both approaches are right in my mind, though the first one makes intuitively more sense because it is specific to the system I use, while the second one is independent of the magnetic circuit. However, I am uncertain as to which approach is physically correct. I would appreciate your consultation and help.

Comment: Both formulae are approximations and for the second equation perhaps as an approximation the effective length is the length of the core.

Comment: if $\mu_{core} \gg \frac{\ell_{core}}{\ell_{gap}}$ then most of the energy is concentrated in the gap not in the core.  That is the point of gapping! [See](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778553/inductance-in-gapped-core-vs-a-long-solenoid/778560#778560)

Comment: @hyportnex I know that, but what I'm interested in is the separation force, which is the force needed to create a gap of an infinitesimally small length. This means the size of the gap approaches 0+, which is effectively 0.

Comment: @Farcher Thanks. So I understand that the first equation is more accurate than the second one. My iron core would be much longer than the solenoid length, so the deviation would be large. I will still test the system, of course, but having good initial starting values would help me.